# Is the asynchron type for umlcallself enviroment broken in the tikz-uml package?

Tags: tikz-uml

I do not want to return anything in the umlcallself environment . So I select asynchron as the type. However, when it compiles the return arrow is absent, but it adds the padding as if the return arrow is present. I have a few of these self calls in my diagram and it adds a lot of unnecessary space. How do I remove that padding?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-uml} 
\begin{document}   
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{umlseqdiag}
      \umlactor{Alice}
      \begin{umlcallself}[op={test},return={result}]{Alice} 
      \end{umlcallself}
      \begin{umlcallself}[op={test},type=asynchron]{Alice} 
      \end{umlcallself}
    \end{umlseqdiag}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I tried setting padding = 1.5, but that just scales the arrows down.

Comment: You might want to contact the package author about this.

Comment: Sent a message. Will report back if he doesn't do so himself.

Comment: Fixing the length of the box itself seems to be relatively easy, but fixing the introduced shift if an object is created after it and correcting the length of the lifeline does not seem to be this easy.